# JQuery button handling

Tags: jquery, button

I can't get the button to work and am really lost as to what's going wrong.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$("signup-button").click(function() {
    console.log("hello");
});
});</script>

<div class="username-input form-horizontal">
  <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
  <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button class="signup-button col-sm-1 control-label">Sign in  </button>
```

Comment: `$(".signup-button")`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your selector. You are using a [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector) `signup-button` which looks for an element with tagname `signup-button` like `<signup-button>..</signup-button>`, but in your case `signup-button` is a class name so you need to use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".signup-button").click(function() {
    console.log("hello");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="username-input form-horizontal">
  <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
  <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
</div>
<button class="signup-button col-sm-1 control-label">Sign in</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing class selector `.`. `$("signup-button")` will look for element having tagname signup-button. thus you should be using `$(".signup-button")`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".signup-button").click(function() {
     console.log("hello");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Select by id. for using #

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#signup").click(function() {
                    console.log("hello");
                    alert("hello");
                });
            });

        </script>
```

```html
<div class="username-input form-horizontal">
            <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
            <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="signup-button col-sm-1 control-label" id="signup">Sign in  </button>
    </body>
```